# .htaccess error while url forwarding

Tags: .htaccess

Here is the .htaccess entry.  what I intended to do is to transfer anyone typing as **www.yahoo.com/Hello** to **www.yahoo.com/index.php?h=hello.**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /index.php?u=$1
```

Now for some reason it shows me a 404 error when I type in yahoo.com too, I wonder what is wrong.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: You can use example.com, example.net and example.org in your questions. These domains are reserved for such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Line 2 and 3 will apply a condition to the `RewriteRule` to make sure it doesn't redirect if the requested URL is a valid file or directory.

Comment: As long as you have the apache module `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled it should work.